# Matlab adding extra columns to a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that is 216 x 3 in size. I wish to add an extra three columns to this matrix. Something I thought was quite simple is driving me crazy! I was expecting it to be something like the line below,

```
myData = [myData; zeros(length(myData(:,1)),3)]
```

The error message is below. However both matrices have the same number of rows so do not understand what the problem is.

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

**UPDATE**

I now have the following line below and I still can get an error message, same as above but for horzcat.

```
myData = [myData zeros(size(myData, 1),3)];
```

I have also noticed myData is actually defined as 213 x3 cell - could this be the issue?

Comment: `myData = [myData zeros(size(myData,1),3)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to pad zeros into arrays would be using [**`padarray`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/padarray.html) -

```
N = 3; %%// Number of columns to be added
myData = padarray(myData,[0 N],'post')
```

**Response to OP's UPDATE:**

```
col_ind = size(myData,2)+1:size(myData,2)+3;
```

One of these must work - `myData(:,col_ind) = {'0'}` or `myData(:,col_ind) = {0}` depending on if a cell array of characters or numerals is needed respectively.

Comment: thanks Divaka. Are you able to tell me why my attempt does not work?

Comment: @mHelpMe That `;` between `myData` and `zeros..` was the mistake, as it was doing vertical concatenation, whereas you were looking to add columns, that is horizontal concatenation. So, you were needed to remove that `;`.

Comment: Ah I see thanks. I have updated my question as I still cannot seem to get my code to work.

Comment: One of these must work - `myData(:,[4:6]) = {'0'}` or `myData(:,[4:6]) = {0}` depending on if you want a cell array of characters or numerals respectively.

Comment: yes thank-you that does work! Think I'm going to end up pulling my hair out using MATLAB

Comment: Make sure to ask about `pulling out hair using MATLAB` on SO before doing so!

Comment: `padarray` is seriously underappreciated. +1  Cleanest solution if you have the toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

```
myData = [ myData zeros(size(myData,1),3) ];
```

Or, more simply:

```
myData(end,end+3) = 0;
```

Comment: Was my mistake not including the size function?

Comment: `length(matrix)` is equivalent to `max(size(matrix))` (only for 2D arrays). So `length` may return the number of rows or of columns. But your mistake was the `;`, which is used for contatenating rows, not columns

Comment: @LuisMendo Congrats on 20K! `SO` trusts you now :)

Comment: @chappjc Thanks! Yes, `length` is a source of problems. I had never considered it as something terribly bad (as I do consider `'` for transposing instead of `.'`), but its gaining points on my pet peeve list :-)

Comment: @Divakar Thank you! The bad side is, there are no privileges left for me to gain anymore :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I noticed that as you were going slow on `rep` lately ;)

Comment: @Divakar Haha, very shrewd. The large amount of work I've been having lately might also have something to do, though ;-)